# SQL QUERY - distinct rows edit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I m working on a SQL query

Below is the output :

```
PT_NO          PT_AGE         PT_SEX      DISEASE_CODE    PT_BILL_AMOUNT
--------     --------       --------     -----------     --------------   
1               50            M               52.01X         100.00
1               50            M               52.01X         100.00
1               50            M               52.01X         100.00
2               40            F               74.01          300.00
2               40            F               74.01          300.00
2               40            F               74.01          300.00
```

Below are the table structure:

```
PATIENT(pt_no,pt_age,pt_sex,pt_bill_amount)
PATIENT_DISEASE(pt_no,disease_code)


SELECT 
  pt_no,pt_age,pt_sex
  ,patient_disease.disease_code
  ,patient.pt_bill_amount
from patient "patient"
    inner join patient_disease "patient_disease" 
    on patient.pt_no = patient_disease.pt_no
```

Somehow I m looking for a way to not repeat the Bill amount (100 and 300 only once) , so that when i sum on the above view created , I get the correct the bill amount as

```
PT_NO          PT_AGE         PT_SEX      DISEASE_CODE    PT_BILL_AMOUNT
--------     --------       --------     -----------     --------------   
1               50            M               52.01X         100.00
1               50            M               52.01X         0.00
1               50            M               52.01X         0.00
2               40            F               74.01          300.00
2               40            F               74.01          0.0
2               40            F               74.01          0.0
```

Any input on the same would be helpful !!!

Thanks !!!

Comment: Can you explain the point of returning rows 2-3 and 5-6 then?

Comment: add a `distinct` to your query and get 2 rows. why do you want to see 6 rows?

Answer (score 1):

If you want those rows to be blank, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select pt_no, pt_age, pt_sex
    ,disease_code
    ,case 
      when rn = 1 
      then pt_bill_amount
      else 0.00
    end as pt_bill_amount
from
(
  SELECT 
    p.pt_no, p.pt_age, p.pt_sex
    , pd.disease_code
    , p.pt_bill_amount
    , row_number() over(partition by p.pt_no, pd.disease_code order by p.pt_no, pd.disease_code) rn
  from patient p
  inner join patient_disease pd
      on p.pt_no = pd.pt_no
) x
order by pt_no, disease_code, rn
```

Comment: I gave you +1, but you have 2 commas before row_number(). It would also be useful to have an ORDER BY to show the $ on the first row per group. Arrr. noticed even more problems... retracting

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi found a few more issues an fixed them, ordering by pt_no and disease_code

Comment: pt_no (alone) + rn may not yet be enough to display properly

Comment: it is not just pt_no, I am partitioning by pt_no and disease_code

Comment: But your display is sorting by pt_no alone. Then rn.

Comment: added order by disease as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` function to choose one row per group, the using case function display the amount in only that row. Like that:

```
SELECT pt_no,
       pt_age,
       pt_sex,
       patient_disease.disease_code,
       CASE
         WHEN ( ( Row_number()
                    OVER(
                      partition BY pt_no, pt_age, pt_sex,
                    patient_disease.disease_code
                      ORDER BY pt_no, pt_age, pt_sex,
                    patient_disease.disease_code) ) =
                1 ) THEN patient.pt_bill_amount
         ELSE 0
       END AS pt_bill_amount
FROM   patient "patient"
       INNER JOIN patient_disease "patient_disease"
               ON patient.pt_no = patient_disease.pt_no
```